# What does it mean for a set of matrices to be a "algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

My book claims that a nonempty collection A of matrices is called an "algebra" if it is closed under matrix addition, scalar and matrix multiplication.

Can anyone explain what it means by closed?

Can anyone provide a counter example how a set of matrix is no longer an algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set, $S$, is *closed* under an operation $\star$ if for any $A,B\in S$ you have that $A\star B \in S$

Take an example: The set of all $n\times n$ matrices whose determinant is one.  This set is closed under multiplication, since $det(A\cdot B) = det(A)\cdot det(B) = 1\cdot 1 = 1$, therefore $A\cdot B\in S$.  It is not however closed under addition, since $det(Id + Id) = 2^n\neq 1$ so there exist $A,B$ where $A+B\notin S$.  Therefore, the set of all $n\times n$ matrices whose determinant is one is *not* an algebra (since it fails to be closed under addition).

---

Edit: I realize that I did not adequately define what it means to be "closed under scalar multiplication".  Given a scalar field, $F$, and a set $S$, $S$ is *closed under scalar multiplication* if for any $\alpha \in F$ and $A\in S$ you have that $\alpha A\in S$.  Common choices for scalar fields are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Here is another non-example.  Let our scalar field be $\mathbb{R}$. Let $S$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices whose entries are all integers.  Let $A,B\in S$.  You have that $A + B = (a_{i,j}+b_{i,j})_{i,j}$, so each entry is a sum of integers and therefore an integer.  So, $A+B\in S$ and $S$ is closed under matrix addition.  In addition you have that $A\cdot B = (\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}b_{j,i})_{i,j}$ and each entry is a sum of products of integers and therefore an integer, so $A\cdot B\in S$ and $S$ is also closed under matrix multiplication.

It is not however closed under scalar multiplication since $\sqrt{2} A$ has noninteger entries when $A\neq 0_n$, therefore it is also not an algebra (since although it is closed under addition and matrix multiplication, it fails to be closed under scalar multiplication).

Comment: How you figured out det(Id+Id) = 2^n so fast

Comment: @MathNewb The identity matrix, here denoted as $Id$, is the matrix with ones along its diagonal (and zeroes everywhere else).  As I specified that it was an $n\times n$ matrix, specifically there are $n$ ones along the diagonal.  Then $Id+Id$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ twos along the diagonal (and zeroes everywhere else).  The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal, which in this case is $\prod_{i=1}^n 2 = 2^n$

Comment: You smart, I like that

Comment: @MathNewb I realize I had not fully answered the question and have now included information on the definition of what it means to be *closed under scalar multiplication*.

Comment: @JMoravitz : You didn't explicitly say it, though it is clear that you intended it: to be an algebra, a non-empty set of matrices should be closed under matrix addition, closed under matrix multiplication, and closed under multiplication by scalars.

Answer (score 0):

The set of $2\times2$ matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ is a sub-$\mathbf R$-algebra of the algebra of all  $2\times2$ matrices, isomorphic  to the field $\mathbf C$ (actually it is one of the constructions of $\mathbf C$). A rela number $a$ corresponds to the matrix $aI$ and the number $\,\mathrm i\,$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Another example: the ring/algebra of even polynomials over any field $k$ is a subalgebra of $k[x]$, generated over $k$ by $x^2$.

Comment: He asked for examples of sets which are **not** algebras, and the meaning of closed. You've only given an example in answer to the title, without appearing to have read the body.

Comment: I did read the body, mylord. The meaning of ‘closed’ hadnbeen answered by @JMoravitz, and I had nothing to add. I thought useful to give small examples of subalgebras, as it is more likely for a subset of matrices *not* to be a subalgebra than to be one.

Comment: Always better when deliberately posting a non-responsive answer to state so up front, because the OP starts reading answers *expecting an answer,* and, by nature of the site, is already confused and trying hard to understand something.

Answer (score 0):

You can view an algebra as a vector space with multiplication. That is, a set $M$ of matrices is an algebra, if it is a vector space (with respect to matrix addition and scalar multiplication), and if for all $A,B\in M$ also $AB\in M$.

Hence all sets of matrices that are not a vector space are also not an algebra:

The sets of invertible matrices, the sets of orthogonal/unitary matrices.

The set of symmetric matrices is not an algebra (althoug being a vector space):
$$
A=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, B=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2},
AB=\pmatrix{4&2\\1&2}.
$$

All matrix groups are not  algebras: Suppose $M$ is a subset of matrices, such that $M$ with the matrix multiplication is a group.

Now assume $M$ is an algebra. Then with $A\in M$ also $-A\in M$, then also $0=A+(-A)\in M$, which is not invertible, a contradiction.

The most important algebra is the set of all square matrices.

Another example is the following set:
$$
\{ p(A): p \in K[x]\},
$$
i.e. for a given matrix $A$, the evaluation at $A$ of all polynomials.